# Is attending weddings permitted for unmarried couples who are courting?

Tags: nikah

As I understand it, when a young man and woman are in the process of courtship prior to marriage, he is allowed to "view" her and I presume meet under various circumstances.

Would that include attending a wedding together, or would attending a wedding be considered inappropriate?

Answer (score 1):

From a shari'a perspective as long as one isn't married the potential husband/wife is a foreigner. Therefore a meeting of both is only permissible in presence of a mahram of the potential wife.

> " No person (man) should be alone with a woman except when there is a Mahram with her."
> ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1341c))

> ...Behold! A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan. ...
> ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2165), see also [here](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1171))

In some modern fatwa's, conversation via phone was regarded as permissible as long as it isn't leading to anything doubt- or sinful.

Further in a "permissible wedding" men and women shouldn't be mixing for similar reasons, so how could what you've asked been permissible?

Comment: I see. I am not Moslem, so I did not understand that. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I would argue that what's most important is not the specific activities a couple engages in, but the way they treat each other and the people around them. Are they respectful and considerate? Are they honest and open about their intentions? Are they aware of and sensitive to the cultural and social norms of their community?

If a couple can answer 'yes' to these questions, then whether they attend a wedding together or not seems a minor detail. The essence of courtship, after all, is not about following a set of rigid rules, but about getting to know each other, building a relationship based on mutual respect and affection, and making decisions that reflect their shared values and aspirations.

So, if the couple in question finds joy in attending a wedding together, and in doing so, they do not infringe upon the rights, expectations, and comforts of others, then why not?

Comment: Apparently the reason for that is that in moslem societies the sexes are ALWAYS separated, even at formal events like weddings. I did not understand that when I asked the question.